# How to disable non-empty std::set as a function parameter if T is not integral?

Tags: c++, c++14

```
template< typename T >
T getNumber(const std::set<T>& setNumbers = std::set<T>())
{
   T val;

  while(true)
  {
    std::cin >> val; // ignore sanity checking

    if (!setNumbers.empty())
    {
      if (setNumbers.count(val) == 1)
        break;
    }
    else
      break;
  }

  return val;
}
```

Question> Given the above function, I would like to add the following limitation and don't know what the best way is to implement the feature

1> If `T` is integral(`std::integral<T>::value == true`), then the `setNumbers` can be set by the user and the default value is an empty set.

2> If `T` is not integral, then the function `getNumber` doesn't allow any input parameter.

Thank you

Comment: What's wrong `if (!std::integral<T>::value && !setNumbers.empty()) throw whatever;`? Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: yes, this should works. But I am looking for a static check with `std::enable_if` and `std::is_integral` if that is possible. So the user can be notified during the compilation procedure.

Comment: *"`setNumbers` can ONLY be empty"* Do you mean `setNumbers.empty() == true`, or that `getNumber` has to be called without specifying any arguments? In other words, is the argument in `getNumber(std::set<int>{})` an 'empty set' in your understanding?

Comment: @q0987 You can't know at compile time if the `set` is empty or not.  `std::set` is a run time only container.

Comment: How can you do a static check while the set size is not static?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I prefer not to allowing the user to specify the input parameter if the `T` is not integral.

Comment: @all, I updated my questions to clarify the OP. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) you can write two overloads of the function.  One that takes a `T` that is the a integer, and on that takes a `T` that is not an integer.  That would look like

```
// for integers
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value, bool> = true>
T getNumber(const std::set<T>& setNumbers = std::set<T>())

// for non integers
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_integral<T>::value, bool> = true>
T getNumber()
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a reasonable way to do that with only a single function.

But if you use two overloads (with 0 and 1 parameters), it's not that hard:

```
template <typename T>
T getNumber()
{
    // ...
}

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value> * = nullptr>
T getNumber(const std::set<T> &setNumbers)
{
    // ...
}
```

If you don't need SFINAE, you could also use a `static_assert`.